# dataGridView column referencing and nested if statements with CellContentDoubleClick event c#

Tags: c#, winforms, if-statement, datagridview, nested

Hi so i see a lot of posts re: cell referencing in a DGV and nested if statements. The post have got me soo far i am very nearly there or maybe not... i am hoping for some help and open to suggestions.

very simply i need to be able to double click on a certain cells in dgv, on double clicking the cell, if that cell is in certain column it applies a 1 or 0 to its relating column.

So, doubling clicking a cell in column 2 applies a figure one or zero depending to the same row but column 5.

```
so,column 2 relates to 5
      6 relates to 9
      10 relates to 13
      14 relates to 17
      18 relates to 21
      22 relates to 25
```

here is what i have so far..i have messed about alot and have taken it so far however i cannot get it to work independently. so, if i double click all columns change not the relating column. at present this doesn’t work. any help would be welcomed.

```
        private void dataGridViewAcorn_CellContentDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

        commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
        dataAdapter.UpdateCommand = commandBuilder.GetUpdateCommand();//get the update command



        string HW_A = dataGridViewAcorn.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
        string Crwn_A = dataGridViewAcorn.CurrentRow.Cells[9].Value.ToString();
        string HB_A = dataGridViewAcorn.CurrentRow.Cells[13].Value.ToString();
        string OV_A = dataGridViewAcorn.CurrentRow.Cells[17].Value.ToString();
        string Acorn_A = dataGridViewAcorn.CurrentRow.Cells[21].Value.ToString();
        string Brn_A = dataGridViewAcorn.CurrentRow.Cells[25].Value.ToString();

        int columnIndex = dataGridViewAcorn.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;


        if (columnIndex == 2)
        {
            if (HW_A == ("1"))

            {
                dataGridViewAcorn.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value = 0;

            }
            else HW_A = ("0");

            {
                dataGridViewAcorn.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value = 1;

            }


        }



        /*
        System.Text.StringBuilder messageBoxCS = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        messageBoxCS.AppendFormat("{0} = {1}", "ColumnIndex", e.ColumnIndex);
        messageBoxCS.AppendLine();
        messageBoxCS.AppendFormat("{0} = {1}", "RowIndex", e.RowIndex);
        messageBoxCS.AppendLine();
        MessageBox.Show(messageBoxCS.ToString(), "CellConentDoubleClick Event");

        */

        dataGridViewAcorn.DataSource = bindingSourceAcorn;
        bindingSourceAcorn.EndEdit();// updates table in memory 
        dataAdapter.Update(table);//actually the data base 
                                  //MessageBox.Show("Update Successful!");




    }
```

Comment: What is the plan if the cells value is "empty" or NOT 0 or 1?

Comment: from empty to 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, create the column dependency object, so you can avoid the multiple ifs. (*I know, that it is not optional memory allocation, if you want to optimize, you can use a `Dictionary<int, int>` object, but I feel like you don't want to mix that into this problem of yours.)*

If you create an array with size 23, you can have indexes up to 22 (which is the highest indexed column of the ones that could be double clicked).

```
int[23] doubleClickConnections = new int[23];
```

Then, you should define only the indexes that have a double-click connection. So 2,6,10,14,18,22. Like this:

```
doubleClickConnections[2] = 5;
```

*(There seems to be a pattern to your indexes. Your left side indexes are in the form `4n + 2`, and your right side index is always `4n + 5`. This could also be used, but I leave that to you.)*

After you've done this, you should use the `DataGridViewCellEventArgs` class' properties, ColumnIndex and RowIndex. (They return the indexes of the double-clicked cell.):

```
int columnToModify = doubleClickConnections[e.ColumnIndex]; //if e.ColumnIndex is 2, this sets the variable to 5 for example.

int valueToAssign = (new object[] {null, 1}).Contains(
    dataGridViewAcorn.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value
) ? 0 : 1;
dataGridViewAcorn.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[columnToModify].Value = valueToAssign;
```

**This assumes the logic to enter 0 or 1 into the cell to modify is always the same** (if the clicked cell is 0 it puts 1, if it is 1 it puts 0).

---

If you want to do the first part with a `Dictionary<int, int>` object:

```
Dictionary<int, int> doubleClickConnections = new Dictionary<int, int>(6) {
    { 2, 5 },
    { 6, 9 },
    ...
};
```

Then, you reference the dictionary the same way you would reference an array, e.g:

```
doubleClickConnections[2] //which equals 5
```

Comment: Please note that I am not in front of a pc, so there might be minor issues, but this should give you an idea.

Comment: thank you, i have looked into both your suggestions. Using the first - i have ran into problems when the dependent cell starts with 1. your original edit didn't like the very final part  1 ? 0 : 1; i am sure its something very fundamental i have missed or i am not understanding. However the cells original state is null or empty so null ? 1 : 0   or    null ? 0: 1  works but only one way on a orginal state cell. if the value is 1 it dost re-vert back 0 and the continue to be a 1 or 0 depending thereafter.

Comment: when tested on original state cell being null everything works independently and resolves a huge part of the little muddle i have got into which is great. cheers.

Comment: int columnToModify = doubleClickConnections[e.ColumnIndex]; //if e.ColumnIndex is 2, this sets the variable to 5 for example.

            dataGridViewAcorn.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[columnToModify].Value =
            dataGridViewAcorn.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value == null ? 1 : 0;

Comment: so initially the cell you double click on is not set to 0 or 1, but it is null?

Comment: yes correct. cell state starts null. once double clicked it will go to 1 double click again to 0 and then if double clicked back 1 and just go round like that on double click event. not even sure if that is possible

Comment: sure it's possible. see my edit. Create an array with values null and 1. Then check with Contains() method, that the expression inside is one of the values in the array. If it is found in the array (so it is null or 1), then return 0. Otherwise, return 1.